# In Java, how super.clone() method "knows" which object has called it?

Tags: java, inheritance, clone, super

I'm really confusing with this (maybe it sounds strange to you, sorry about that). For example, if I have class A and override clone method and in body I have super.clone().. It calls clone() method from Object class, and my question is HOW clone method in Object class knows which object to clone.. 
Maybe I do not understand well super (I know when use this that you know to use current object of class).

Comment: The implementation of `clone()` is "magic" -- it's not something normal Java code could implement, it's built into the language (really, into the JVM).

Comment: Its black vodoo magic, directly implemented in the JVM, not as Java code. On top of that, its rather bad and has soo many issues. Just dont use it, prefer explicit copy-constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Java classes, if they do not define an explicit `extends`, extend `Object`. A call to `super.clone()` or really any call to `super.someMethod()` will call the implementation of that method one link up in the class hierarchy instead of calling the implementation of that method defined in the class.

Take for instance

```
public class A {
    public void someMethod(){
        System.out.println("A.someMethod()");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class B extens A {
    @Override
    public void someMethod(){
        super.someMethod(); //call the implementation of someMethod() as defined in A
        System.out.println("B.someMethod()");
    }
}
```

This:

```
new A().someMethod();
```

will print `A.someMethod();`

And this:

```
new B().someMethod();
```

Will print

```
A.someMethod()
B.someMethod()
```

---

**EDIT 1**

A slightly more complex example:

```
public class SuperTest {

    public static class A {

        public void someMethod() {
            System.out.println(
                    this.getClass().getSimpleName()+".someMethod()");
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {

        @Override
        public void someMethod() {
            super.someMethod();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B().someMethod();
    }
}
```

Will print `B.someMethod()`

`super` is used to call an implementation higher up the class hierarchy but it is still called on the object that is doing `super` call.

---

**EDIT 2**

As this pertains to `clone()`, which is in and of itself not great and should be avoided at all costs. You can read up on the reasons why all over the internet.

A canonical implementation of `clone()` really requires all classes in the class hierarchy of a Class to provide a canonical implementation of `clone()`. The implementation of `clone()` should start with a call to `super.clone()` because we expect that the parent class will do the cloning of all that class's members and assign them and return the object. Then the child class's `clone()` implementation should then copy its member fields and assign them to the clone.

We can see this happening in the expanded example

```
public class SuperCloneTest {

    public static class A implements Cloneable {

        private String member1;

        public A(String value) {
            this.member1 = value;
        }

        @Override
        public Object clone() {
            System.out.println("In A.clone()");
            System.out.printf("Class of `this` in A.clone(): %s\n", this.getClass().getSimpleName());
            A clone;
            try {
                clone = (A) super.clone();

                System.out.printf("Class of clone in A.clone(): %s\n", clone.getClass().getSimpleName());
                System.out.printf("Value of member1 in A.clone(): %s\n", this.member1);

                clone.member1 = this.member1;

                return clone;
            } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
                //A implements Cloneable so we can be sure this won't happen
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {

        private String member2;

        public B(String value1, String value2) {
            super(value1);
            this.member2 = value2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object clone() {
            System.out.println("In B.clone()");
            System.out.printf("Class of `this` in B.clone(): %s\n", this.getClass().getSimpleName());

            B clone = (B) super.clone();
            System.out.printf("Class of clone in B.clone(): %s\n", clone.getClass().getSimpleName());
            System.out.printf("Value of member2 in B.clone(): %s\n", this.member2);

            clone.member2 = this.member2;

            return clone;
        }
    }

    public static class C extends B {

        private String member3;

        public C(String value1, String value2, String value3) {
            super(value1, value2);
            this.member3 = value3;
        }

        @Override
        public Object clone() {
            System.out.println("In C.clone()");
            System.out.printf("Class of `this` in C.clone(): %s\n", this.getClass().getSimpleName());

            C clone = (C) super.clone();
            System.out.printf("Class of clone in C.clone(): %s\n", clone.getClass().getSimpleName());
            System.out.printf("Value of member3 in C.clone(): %s\n", this.member3);

            clone.member3 = this.member3;

            return clone;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new C("value1", "value2", "value3").clone();
    }
}
```

And when we run it we get this:

```
In C.clone()
Class of `this` in C.clone(): C
In B.clone()
Class of `this` in B.clone(): C
In A.clone()
Class of `this` in A.clone(): C
Class of clone in A.clone(): C
Value of member1 in A.clone(): value1
Class of clone in B.clone(): C
Value of member2 in B.clone(): value2
Class of clone in C.clone(): C
Value of member3 in C.clone(): value3
```

Here we can see that `this` is always C and so is the clone. Going all the way up the stack and calling `super.clone()` in `A` calls `Object.cone()` which will allocate and object of the same type as `this`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I understand this, but in this example we just call parent class method and print something, and we just do not have to know which object has called that. But in case of clone method, it has to know which object has called that method in order to clone that. I hope that you understand my confusion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually how Object class knows members from child class in order to clone that members. 
I think that it is same like we would access data in class B from class A, what is impossible, because parent class do not know which additional data are in child class. 
Maybe in this way I better explained my confusion.

Comment: @DevPer I added some more examples and explanation. Hopefully that clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

The clone method in Object is a default implementation.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I understand that, but in that override method we usually call super.clone() method for shallow copy. And in this case I do not understand how Java knows which object has called this clone method from Object class, because we just say super. clone(), and I think that it means just to call clone method from parent (Object) class, we do not tell which object to clone.

Comment: P.S. I understand when call object.clone() method directly and in this way it is logic to me, because in this way clone method from Object class knows which object to clone, because we call clone method with certain object.. But in super.clone() we do not specify which object has call that. I hope that you understand my question.